# How can I match repeating substrings with a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression in JavaScript that will replace multiple instances of the same string pattern.

Lets say I have the following string:

`<li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li>`

There's no new line character between each list item, and I want to match each individual list item (e.g. `item 1`, `item 2`, `item 3`).

Currently, I've only managed to get it to match the whole string by using `/<li>(.*)<\/li>/g`

Is there a way to do this in javascript regex?

Comment: You should not use regex for this. Just parse the string.

Comment: If you're actually using this for HTML, just FYI: you'll run into a lot of edge cases parsing HTML using regular expressions. Unless you're expecting very simple, constrained HTML (i.e. not random HTML entered by a user), you'll likely be OK. But if you're creating a generic tool for processing HTML of any kind, it won't work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Match sequence of characters which are not `<` or `>` (`[^<>]+`), and has the `<` character after it (`+(?=<)`) (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nx1Bmv/1)):

```js
const str = '<li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li>'

const result = str.match(/[^<>]+(?=<)/g)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to parse the string and use the DOM management functions of Javascript.

```js
var htmlString = '<li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li>'
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

htmlDocument .querySelectorAll('li').forEach(el => {
  console.log(el.innerText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `/<*.li>/gm`. `str.replace(/<*.li>/gm, ' ')` will give you the string with just the items

https://regex101.com/r/FG9Y7k/1

Still learning regex myself so probably some better answers

edit:
If you want to match just inside the tags here's another
https://regex101.com/r/qPtSBi/1
`/(?<=\>)(.*?)(?=<)/g`